# How To Submit Form Data From B-modal In Vue

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

So I am having a issue trying to submit form data from a `b-modal` in my Vue component. I can see in my dev tools that the data object is being populated with the data however when I submit my form It doesn't send my data.

here is the form

```
 <b-modal v-model="modalShow" id="myModal">
      <form>
        <div>
          <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="user.name">
          <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" v-model="user.email">
          <br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Password" v-model="user.password">
          <br>
        </div>
        <div>
          <b-btn @click="modalShow = false">Cancel</b-btn>
          <b-btn variant="outline-primary" @click="addUser">Create</b-btn>
        </div>
      </form>
    </b-modal>
```

Here is the data object and method from the component

```
data() {
    return {
       modalShow: false,
       user: {
          name: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
       }
    }
  },
  components:{
    'b-modal': bModal,
  },
  directives: {
    'b-modal': bModalDirective
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['users']),
  },
  methods: {
    addUser() {
      this.$store.dispatch('addUser', {
          name: this.user.name,
          email: this.user.email,
          password: this.user.password,
      })
    }
   },
```

and here is the store method being dispatched

```
addUser(user) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post('/register', {
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          resolve(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error.response.data)
        })
      })
    },
```

if I do a return response before processing the data on my back end it shows a empty data object. any ideas why?

Comment: axios.post('/register', {
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
        })

this.user.name,
this.user.email,
this.user.password
Test

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel, are you saying to change `name: user.name` to `name: this.user.name`?

Comment: Correct, test this.

Comment: @HamiltonGabriel, view answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in [vuex action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) is `context` object, the `payload` is passed as the second argument

```
addUser(context, user) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post('/register', {
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          resolve(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error.response.data)
        })
      })
    }
```

Comment: yeah I figured that out after a little bit, but thank you for the comment